# Work with 404 and response from an API

Tags: laravel, api, http-status-code-404, response

I use an API to check voucher code if exist. And if voucher code exist everything is fine but problem is when I enter wrong code then I get this:

```
Client error: `GET https://apidev.example.co.uk/api/v1/vouchers/2869512_1-9FDS` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
{
"Code": 1000,
"Description": "Voucher no. is unknown please check and try again or contact Acorne on 0330 111 04 (truncated...)
```

I have this code in back end (laravel php):

```
$res = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
dd($res);
```

**How I can access code 1000, and remove this error screen?**

UPDATE:
screen when voucher is valid and dd($res);
[image]

Comment: Share the result of `dd($res);`

Comment: How to handle with error messages?

Comment: I update question with image of dd($res) when there is an voucher

Comment: Can you expand the stream object? generally an API would throw a 404 as the status code, but in your case the status code is 200 and a custom code is used. Post the screenshot with the expanded stream object till you find the code.

Comment: http://imgur.com/yR7kXpT

Comment: You're trying to dump the response object. But your code shows `$res = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);`. Pass the response content through json_decode and then post the results of the data.

Comment: Can't seem to find "Description" in that dd

Comment: I write: $res = json_decode($res);
dd($res); and get : json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: When voucher code is wrong then I get : ClientException in RequestException.php line 107:
Client error: `GET https://apidev.example.co.uk/api/v1/vouchers/2869512_1-9FDo` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
{
"Code": 1000,
"Description": "Voucher no. is unknown please check and try again or contact Acorne on 0330 111 04 (truncated...)

Comment: when voucher code excist I get this: http://imgur.com/fSHUJfP but problem is when voucher code is wrong then I get error message and I need to handle that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/39868378/5844171
Seems a try catch is probably what you need for that exception